# Friends don't appear as public in C++

Tags: c++, class, private, public

I wrote a class with a friend declared in the public section:

```
class Graph {
    // ... snip ...

public:
    Graph()= default;
    friend Graph operator+ (const Graph &g1, const Graph &g2);
};
```

But when I write the following in main.cpp:

```
Graph g{};
g.
```

my IDE doesn't show `operator+` as a possible completion.

Is `operator+` not public after all? What's going on?

Comment: why downvoting?

Comment: I imagine because of the almost complete lack of detail.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. State the question properly. E.g. what popup ? There are no popups in C++.

Comment: You have at least posted the class since I made the above comment. Now you could add which IDE you are using.

Comment: I think there's a legitimate C++ question buried in here - it's only phrased in terms of the unnamed IDE

Comment: The `operator+()` is declared as a `friend`.   A `friend` of a class is not a member function of that class.   Since it is not a member function of that class, it cannot be a `public` member function of that class.

Comment: I rollled back your edit.The edit didn't change anything and the answer to that new version of the question would be very similar to the answer I've already given - except the part where I give an example of how to add a member function to the class that would possibly show up when you do `g.`. No matter what members you would add to the class you had before the rollback they would not show up when you do `g.`.

Answer (score 3):

`g.` would make your IDE show the `Graph` member functions.

This is a free (non-member) function:

```
friend Graph operator+ (const Graph &g1, const Graph &g2);
```

If you add a member function, like `operator+=` below, that would possibly show up:

```
class Graph {
private:
    // ... snip ...

public:
    Graph() = default;
    Graph& operator+=(const Graph& rhs);                      // this may show up
    friend Graph operator+(const Graph &g1, const Graph &g2);
};

Graph& Graph::operator+=(const Graph& rhs) {
   // ... impl ...
   return *this;
}

Graph operator+(const Graph &g1, const Graph &g2) {
    Graph retval(g1);
    return retval += g2;
}
```

Note: By making use of the member function `operator+=` from within `operator+` like above, the free function will not need to be a `friend` anymore.